# Open Safari from XCTestCase

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, safari, xctest

According to [Apple's documentaion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiapplication/2879415-init), I should be able to launch an app based on its bundle ID using the code below.

```
// Open safariapp
let safariApp = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.mobilesafari")

// Launch safari app
safariApp.launch()
```

Unfortunately, this code will not compile because Xcode claims that `XCUIApplication` can not take any initialization arguments. This is my error:

```
Argument passed to call that takes no arguments
```

Comment: What version of Xcode and Swift are you using?

Comment: Swift 3 and Xcode 8.3 and I have tried `XCUIApplication(privateWithPath: nil, bundleID: "com.apple.safari")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality is available starting with the Xcode 9 SDK, so you'll need to update your Xcode version and migrate to Swift 3.2 or 4.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuiapplication/2879415-init